# JS - Pass argument to a function with event handler

Tags: javascript, function

i want to pass an argument to a function that already handle the event object:

```
function bla(e){
   //function code
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   return false;
}
```

but i need to call this function from another place passing an argument:

```
bla(arg);
```

And i don't know how... i tried:

```
bla(e, arg); //failed
```

and:

```
function bla(){
     (function (e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
     }());
}//e is undefined
```

and:

```
function bla(){
    var e = window.event;
    //code....
    //e is undefined;
}
```

and others but nothing works, there's something i can do?

Comment: Can you elaborate a specific example? an event can be passed/stored just like anything else.

Comment: `bla(null, arg)`, then conditionally do the preventDefault, stopPropagation only if `e` is an event

Comment: bla(e, arg) this has to work if you change your signature to - function bla(arg, e)

Comment: What you get when you call `bla(e, arg)`? Have you changed function header too? Also why you want to call this function if it's associated with event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to modify your event handlers. You could either use an anonymous function in your handler that will stop propagation etc then call your method. This way the `bla` method doesn't care about handling the event and can be called elsewhere in your code. But if you have many events using this method will duplicate code:

```
someElement.on('someEvent', function(e, data){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    bla(data);
});
```

Another option would be to create another method which handles the event then calls your end event handler with data.

```
function genericEventHandler(fn, context){
    return function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        /*
           This will allow it to call fn with any number of arguments
        */
        var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 1);
        fn.apply(context, args);
    }
}

someElement.on('someEvent', genericEventHandler(bla));
someElementTwo.on('someOtherEvent', genericEventHandler(bla));
```

This way you could create multiple methods for generic behavior across methods, it would also make it easier to change this generic behavior as you only need to change it in one place.

I think the reason your existing attempts fail when you try to manually call `bla` is because the `e` object either doesn't exist (if you haven't passed it in) or doesn't have the correct structure.

EDIT: There is one final option but i really would advise against this in favor of the above options if possible. As others have said you really should avoid linking your application and event logic. Splitting these apart will stop you needing to provide `null/undefined` as the first param to `bla` if you or others on the team forget it will cause strange bugs. It will also make your event handler easier to test and more usable elsewhere in your application if needed.

```
function bla(e, data){
    if (e !== undefined) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    //do something with data
}

bla(undefined, 'some random data');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for all, i have the answer:

```
function bla(e, data){
     //code...
     if(e !== NULL){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
     }
}
```

It's works perfect.

bla(null, data)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution but i really would advise against this option. As other said you really should avoid linking your application and event logic. Splitting these apart will stop you needing to provide null as the first param to `bla` if you or others forget it will cause strange bugs. It will also make your event handler easier to test and more usable elsewhere in your application if needed. Ill update my answer with this too for others.